# Singularity information about $AB=CD^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

We only know that $B$ is a $n\times n$ singular matrix and 
$D$ is a $n\times n$ non-singular matrix. 
We have no idea singularity for $A$ and $C$.

If $AB=CD^{-1}$ holds, do we get any information about singularity 
for $A$ and/or $C$?

Comment: $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ and $\det(CD^{-1})=\det(C)\det(D^{-1})$.  Now, what does singularity have to do with determinant?  What is $\det(B)$ equal to?  what does that mean $\det(AB)$ is equal to?  What does that mean $\det(CD^{-1})$ is equal to?  Finally, what does this mean $\det(C)$ is equal to?

Comment: As for tag usage, please *read* what the tag is about before using it.  Singularity theory has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming $A$ and $C$ are also $n \times n$.  Since $B$ is singular, $AB$ is also singular, so $C = ABD$ must be singular.  But $A$ could be anything.

Comment: It is greatly appreciated.